# In Graph Theory is this true Proof for In any simple graph there are at least two nodes with the same degree

Tags: data-structures, computer-science, graph-theory

By the definition of Edge :
 if we could find at least one edge, >> this mean we obviously get 2 nodes , and this means : these nodes : are sharing the same edge, so this means they have the same degree .

So please if my proof is correct or not ?

Thanks

Comment: I would say it's correct for the two-node single-edge case. It's quite a long ways from being a complete proof for the general case, though...

Comment: Nodes sharing the same edge don't necessarily have the same degree - that would be a silly assumption - try drawing some graphs and you should see that this doesn't hold most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Proof is not correct like Dukeling explained.

It can be done by checking is there a cons example. In graph with `n` nodes, only possibility for these nodes to have different degree is to have degrees `{0, 1, 2, ..., n-1}`, since maximal degree is `n-1`. That means one node is not connected to any other node (degree 0), and because of that it is not possible to have node with degree `n-1`. That means it is not possible to construct cons example, which means the statement is true.

Comment: In the general case, there can be multiple edges between any two nodes, meaning there is no maximum degree... What you say is true for a restricted sub-class of graph that has a maximum of one edge between any two nodes, though...

Comment: @twalberg It is stated, in title, for simple graphs.

Comment: You're right... It's been a long time since my university days - had to refresh my memory on what made a graph "simple" - I was thinking it had more to do with connectedness... Ah, well...